# How to remove files from a Windows folder using the shell() command

Tags: r

I have s script that produces a lot of small PNG files that I want to remove when I close my gWidgets interface. I thought I could do that in Windows using

```
shell( "del *.png" )
```

but neither in the script nor in interactive mode in R (2.15.2), this has any effect at all (not even an error or warning). Probably I'm doing something wrong but I can't find out so far what.

Has somebody an idea for me?

Comment: You might want to consider using `unlink` or `file.remove`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just tested your command -- same version of R on Windows XP -- and it works exactly as you would expect. If this command is not working for you, I strongly suspect that R's working directory may be different from the directory in which you have your .png files.

You could try:

```
shell('dir *.png')
```

... to verify that the .png files are, in fact, in the current working directory before trying to delete them. If they are not there, you will get the report:

```
File Not Found
Warning messages:
1: running command 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c dir *.png' had status 1 
2: In shell("dir *.png") : 'dir *.png' execution failed with error code 1
```

Also, if you've run the `del` command once, so there are no .png files remaining in the directory, the second time that you run that command you should get an error message like the following:

```
> shell("del *.png")
Could Not Find C:\usr\sjl\dev\test\R\*.png
```

Comment: My bad! I took it for granted (and therefore didn't mention) that the command also works on sub-directories - my actual command was `del out/*.png`. In Linux this works: `system( 'rm out/*.png' )`...